# Ум и разум

Tags: словообразование

Мне интересно, как из слова "ум" образовалось слово "раз-ум"? Почему тут приставка "раз"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В приставке нет ничего удивительного. Она может, помимо прочего, означать высшую степень: разудалый, распрекрасный и т.д. Предположу, что разумный было из этой же серии.
Я правда не очень понимаю, насколько это согласуется с тем, что в "разум" церковнославянский вокализм, исконноруское было "розум", в каком виде сохранилось и в большинстве славянских.